Theorem : For any two real numbers $a,b$ with $a < b: [a,b]$ is uncountable
This is a Theorem in the book, "A Course on Borel Sets" [[ SM Srivastava 2001 ]] I was reading and I understood nearly everything but a statement which gives the contradiction, I am attaching the proof, highlighting the statement I didn't get

My main question is how can we get $b_i > x:= \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} b_n$, the supremum of the $b_n$.

This proof looks incomplete to me $-$ I don't see why $i_n$ and $j_n$ must exist. For instance, if $a_n=a$ for all $n$, then $i_0$ doesn't exist $-$ there is no $i$ such that $b_0<a_i$. I think the idea is to assume that the range of $(a_n)$ is equal to $[a,b]$, and then derive a contradiction; but they haven't done this! This approach is used for instance here.

@TonyK - It's true that there is a little bug in that proof. You can indeed fix it by assuming that the range of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ coincides with $[a, b]$. But you can also fix it with a minimal change that is more faithful to the original spirit of the proof in the book, see my answer below.

The proof presented in Rudin PMA is clear to me.

I would like to just point out that while my answer is easy to process & is correct & is adding what was missing in the text , the other answer is not covering your Doubt at all , more-over other users have pointed out mistakes there. It is up to you to accept which-ever answer you wish. You might want to think over the Solutions given to consider which is more useful to you & to your Doubt.

Was my valid answer not sufficient to accept it , which will mark this query resolved ?

Proof outline makes sense , though I think it is quite short while missing out some necessary words , making the audience to think more.
OP : My main question is how can we get $b_i > x:= \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} b_n$, the supremum of the $b_n$.
Short Answer : We can not , hence the Contradiction !
Proof Outline , in my words :
Let the Sequence $\left<A_n\right>$ cover the whole range $[a,b]$
It will have Countable number of Elements , hence every range will have some minimum element.
We make $\left<B_n\right>$ increase , while making $\left<C_n\right>$ decrease.
We choose 2 minimum elements such that $B_n < A_i < A_j < C_n$
We then let $A_i$ go to $B$ Sequence while letting $A_j$ go to $C$ Sequence.
We choose the Supremum of $\left<B_n\right>=x$ , which is naturally less than $C$ Sequence , hence we must have some $A$ Sequence element left over , to cover the range $[x,b]$
Let the $A$ Sequence have some such element $A_k=x$
That $k$ would have occurred when we made the $B$ Sequence earlier , to generate some element $B_t$.
When we had then generated the element $B_{t+1}$ , then it should have exceeded $A_k=x$ , which is the Supremum of $B$ Sequence : It is a Contradiction !
Hence $\left<A_n\right>$ can not have the range we want , which is uncountable.

Your argument is correct, but it is another proof, structurally different from the one written in the book. It's true that there is a little bug there,  but it can be easily fixed with a minimal change that is more faithful to the original spirit of the proof in the book, see my answer below.

Indeed, there is no $b_i > x$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$ because $x = \sup\{b_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. And this is exactly what the proof wants to show!
The proof takes any sequence $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of countably infinite elements of the interval $[a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (it does not say "countably infinite", but this is crucial, see below; this is the only mistake in the proof of the book), and it shows that there is always a $x \in [a,b]$ that is not in $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Indeed, if $x = a_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there would be a contradiction. This means that the interval $[a, b]$ is uncountable.
Where is the contradiction? Assume that there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k = x$, where $x = \sup \{b_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \in [a,b]$.
Because of the way the sequence $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is defined, this implies that $b_i > x$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$. But this is impossible, as you correctly said, because $b_i \leq x$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ by definition of $x$.

It seems to me that there is a little bug in the proof as it is written in the book. It takes a sequence $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ whatever in the interval $[a,b]$. But this is not enough. To build the sequences $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(c_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ it is required that the $a_i$'s are pairwise distinct, or at least that there are (countably) infinitely many distinct elements in the sequence $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. If $a_i = a$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ or $a_i = b$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $i_0$ is not defined and either is $b_1$. If $a < a_i = a_j < b$ for all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$, then $j_0$ is not defined and either is $c_0$. It seems to me that if there are no infinitely many distinct elements in $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ then $j_n$ and hence $c_n$ and $b_{n+1}$ are not defined.
This is not a real issue because it is enough to replace the first sentence in the proof by saying "Let $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of countably infinite elements of the interval $[a, b]$".

I am not sure : Still thinking. (1) When Author says $i \in N$ , it is automatically countably infinite elements. (2) When the Sequence has repeated elements such that it has finite number of elements , then automatically , that range will not get covered. (3) Contradiction "this is impossible" , that was what OP was asking about here , which I have detailed out in my answer.

Sorry, why can you assume an $a_i$ always exists in the interval $(b_n,c_n)$? That seems to be the main oversight in the proof to me... not mentioning that we can't necessarily do this (regardless of $a_i$ is countably infinite) but in the case we do get stuck, we're done since the interval's nonempty and so there must be an element of $[a,b]$ that is not one of the $a_i.$

In other words , this answer is incomplete , not covering what OP wants , while my answer puts in what was missing in the text Proof which is what OP wants.

@spaceisdarkgreen - By construction an $a_i$ always exists in the interval $(b_n, c_n)$, if you assume that the sequence $(a_i){i \in \mathbb{N}}$ has countably infinitely many elements of $[a,b]$ and it's nondecreasing (you can always get that $(a_i){i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is nondecreasing by rearranging the indices $i \in \mathbb{N}$). You can prove it by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that there is an $a_i \in (b_0, c_0)$ because it's not true that $a_i = a$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ or $a_i = b$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

@Taroccoesbrocco No, say the sequence is injective and strictly increasing (i.e. in order where image has order type $\omega$). For your $b_1$ you pick $a_0$ or $a_1,$ depending on whether $a_0=a$ or not. Then for your $c_1$ you pick $a_1$ in the first case or $a_2$ in the second. Either way there are no more $a_i$'s in $[b_1,c_1].$ (Of course there are obviously no sequences of order type $\omega$ that cover $[a,b]$ anyway and all the points in $[b_1,c_1]$ witness that but that's the case analysis I claimed was missing. )

@Taroccoesbrocco (Also, the image of the sequence could have any countable order type, so you can't necessarily rearrange the sequence to be non-decreasing.)

@Taroccoesbrocco: You have not fixed the proof, I'm afraid. To make the proof work, you have to assume (for a contradicition) that the range of $(a_n)$ is the whole of $[a,b]$. Otherwise $i_n$ and $j_n$ might not exist.
